# How do I put colored carpet on my head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was messing with command blocks today and I tried to put colored carpet on my head. I don't really know that much about command blocks and that kind of stuff. I already know `/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head minecraft:carpet 1 0`, but I want to know the command for colored carpet.

Answer (score 4):

The `replaceitem` syntax for entities is:

```
/replaceitem entity <selector> <slot> <item> [amount] [data] [dataTag]
```

The carpet's colour is represented by its data value (sometimes called "damage value"). Currently you have it set to 0, which is white. You can see these values [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Wool.2C_Stained_Clay.2C_Stained_Glass_and_Carpet).

For example, for lime carpet:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head minecraft:carpet 1 5
```

Comment: Thanks SirBenet- I haven't been on this website in a while, and I realized that you answered my old question already. I figured the answer out months later.. I'm an idiot.